# Go to a specific slide on a slideshow with a button

Tags: javascript, slideshow

Is there a way that I can make a button turn the slideshow that I have to a specific slide, as in I press the button and the slideshow will display slide 5 for example?

I've tried to just make a button with `onlick=showDivs(5)` as suggested by another person, but that just seems to refresh the current slide, instead of showing the fifth one

Here's my slideshow code:

```
<div>
    <img class="mySlides" src="1.jpg">
    <img class="mySlides" src="2.jpg">
    <img class="mySlides" src="3.jpg">
</div>
<button class="w3-button w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">Previous</button>
<button class="w3-button w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs(+1)">Next</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var slideIndex = 1;
    showDivs(slideIndex);

    function plusDivs(n) {
        showDivs(slideIndex += n);
    }

    function showDivs(n) {
        var i;
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
        if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
        if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length};
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].style.display = "none"; 
        }
        x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
    }

    setInterval(function(){
        $('.mySlides').click()
    },1000)
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to write the function like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(index) {
 slideIndex = index;
}

function plusDivs(n) {
    showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length};
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none"; 
    }
    x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
}

setInterval(function(){
    $('.mySlides').click()
},1000)
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to it myself by just trying random things, finally I just added "onclick="showDivs(slideIndex=5)" to a simple button and it worked